# TFS: How do I cleanup the messed up server?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm using TFS to connect to codeplex.com.  The source version of the project is messed up, and I want to replace it.  Found a way to delete the project, but it won't let me delete it.  How can I say delete all of the subprojects without deleting the representative folders on the hard drive?

Note: this is codeplex so I have limited issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to delete the folders on the server but not delete anything locally.  You then want to re-add your code using what you have locally.  Is that correct?

Possibly the easiest way to do this is to copy the code you have locally into a separate back-up folder on your desktop.  Then perform a delete using Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio.  Check-in the delete.  Finally drag/drop the contents of your local back-up into Source Control Explorer (you need Visual Studio 2008 SP1 for drag/drop to work) so that it adds the appropriate files for you to.

Check the pending adds that you have to make sure all the files you want are included and no files you do not want (i.e. make sure any compilation outputs are not included and that the folder format in source control explorer is how you want it to be)

Once you are happy, check-in your adds.

Let me know if I didn't understand the question correctly.

Comment: I was hoping that there was another solution.  Seems weird that MS didn't think of the ability to let us manage the folder structure on both ends, like VSS does (can't believe I'm touting a VSS feature of TFS :-D).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against doing that. TFS can get confused by deleting and re-adding. At least, that is the case if you have any branching & merging to do. If not... well, go ahead.